# Global Values in VB

Tags: vb.net, variables

**The scenario**

I'm creating a simple cafe order form in visual studio.
I have one form to take orders and another as a summery page.

On the orders form i have a button "Save/ New order" when this button is pressed the order gets added to a listbox. I also want to create and accumulator to count the number of orders taken. I decided to create a global variable because i will only use this number in the summary form.

This is what ive done so far.

```
Public Class GlobalValues
    Private Shared pItemIterator As Integer
    Public Shared Property orderCounter As Integer
        Get
            Return pItemIterator
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            pItemIterator = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And for the button

```
GlobalValues.orderCounter+= 1
```

**The Problem**

I currently stuck on how to minus -1 from this value. On the order form I have a button to remove the last order.

Comment: `...orderCounter -= 1` ??  Also vba <> VB.NET

Comment: There is no property named ItemIterator in class shown. Do you mean orderCounter?

Comment: @Jeremy: Surely _minus -1_ = +1 anyway? ;)

Comment: @Ieuan Walker Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access pItemIterator as you made it private. You need to use the public `Property` you made for it:

```
GlobalValues.orderCounter -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay for you to make a public sub for it that will deal with pItemIterator?

```
    Public Class GlobalValues
    Private Shared pItemIterator As Integer
    Public Shared Property orderCounter As Integer
        Get
            orderCounter = pItemIterator
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            pItemIterator = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Sub subtractOneFromOrderCounter()
        pItemIterator = pItemIterator - 1
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Then you would set subtractOneFromOrderCounter() to be called when your button is clicked.